# Remove items from List<T> where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I got a `List<Person> listA`  -> where `Person` has

```
string name
int age
List<string> jobs
```

I need to remove from listA all items that `jobs.count() < 1`, using linq, any ideas?

Comment: `List<T>` already has a `RemoveAll` method that accepts a predicate - have you tried using that? (I would suggest posting the code rather than a description of the code - it'll be a lot easier to help you.)

Comment: What did you try already? There are plenty of similar questions on how to remove items from a list using some condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate a list using LINQ, because it's designed for querying, however, `List<T>` already has a [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) method as part of it's protocol:

```
listA.RemoveAll(person => person.Jobs.Count < 1);
```

`RemoveAll` accepts a [`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1) delegate which should return true when an item is to be removed.

However, if you're intention is to create a *new list* that only contains people with less than one job, you can use LINQ:

```
var newList = listA
    .Where(person => person.Jobs.Count < 1)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The second solution (a new list) seems cleaner and more LINQ-ish.

Comment: @XouDo It entirely depends whether the OP wants to update the existing list or not.

Comment: For sure, that's what the OP wants to do, but I think there are really few case where you *need* to modify a list instead of just passing a new filtered one.